# Polymorphic for storing information about several objects/entities at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Say, I have a model Activity. And I want to use it as a model for kind of news or event happening on my website such:

> a user has created an article
>
> a user has edited an article
>
> a user has deleted a comment
>
> a user has uploaded a picture

There always be a connection to a User. And to something else: Article, News, Comment, Picture, Profile. How can I implement this? I can do this:

```
Activity
  belongs_to :with_activity, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user



 Articles
   has_many :activities, as :with_activity 

 News
   has_many :activities, as :with_activity
```

But when I'm creating an activity, how would I specify **all** the IDs involved?

For example:
  "A user has added a comment for an article". There're 3 entities here. User id is captured via "belongs_to :user". But either Comment ID or Article is captured via "belongs_to :with_activity, polymorphic: true" and not both. Whereas I want both. Or more if needed:

"A user has added a comment for a picture of an article". -- 4 entities, but only IDs of 2 of them are captures. I need to store all their IDs. "polymorphic" allows to store only an ID of a single entity.

How can I get around of that? Should I add "belongs_to" :picture, :article, :comment and so to Activity? Is there a better solution?

Note that I don't want to use a gem for that.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you only need the association to the `with_activity`. From that you can follow the already existing `belongs_to` associations (I assume a comment `belongs_to` an article).

For example: *A user has added a comment for an article*:

```
# User creates a comment
comment  = user.comments.create(article: article, text: 'Lorem ipsum')
# store the comment creation activity
activity = user.activities.create(with_activity: comment, activity: 'created')
```

Now you want to know render the activity:

```
<%= activity.user.name %>                               # John Do
<%= activity.activity %>                                # created
<%= activity.with_activity.class.to_s %>                # Comment
"<%= activity.with_activity.text %>"                    # "Lorem ipsum"
on <%= link_to 'Article', user.with_activity.article %> # on <Article Link>
```

Or for your other example: *A user has added a comment for a picture of an article* If `user_activity` is the user's activity than

```
user_activity.with_comment.picture.acticle
```

would return the corresponding article.

Comment: `I assume a comment belongs_to an article` -- yes, but only in this particular example.

Comment: what if I had several entities not related to each other?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand how someone can do an activity on multiple things that aren't related to each other? I would assume that the things need to be connected or will be connected by the object created by the action the users does. Can you post an example in which that is not the case?

Comment: If you need your Activity to belong to several not related objects, then do it with `many-to-many` relation. Add another class, something like `ActivityAction`. ActivityAction belongs to Activity and belongs to polymorphic object. Activity belongs to user and has many :activity_actions. User has many :activity_actions THROUGH :activities